# Find minimum number of blockage needed to prevent A from reaching B

Tags: algorithm, search, path-finding

> You are given a 2D array representing a map e.g.:
>
> A .  X .
>
> . . . .
>
> X X . B
>
> Note: '.' represents traversable positions 'X' represents
> non-traversable positions
>
> **THE QUESTION**:
>
> **Find the minimum number of blockage you can add to prevent A from reaching B.**
>
> For the above example, the answer is 1 from a positioning like this:
>
> A . X .
>
> . . % .
>
> X X . B
>
> Note: '%' represents the inserted blockage

**MY ATTEMPT**:

I tried to solve this with a simple DFS thrown to 4 different direction and only increment total blockage number when that specific path leads to B. However this creates problem in marking paths already traversed as marking suboptimal paths arbitrarily might block search effort of other directions.

Any pointers on how to solve this optimally? Or is there any similar coding problems in the same vein as the above problem at Leetcode/Codeforces/etc.?

**EDIT 1**:
According to the answer of [Jacob Steinebronn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13674351/jacob-steinebronn), this problem can be solved with a **Max Flow Algorithm**. So after some time trying to understand the algorithm, this is my new attempt:

1. Construct a directed graph from the 2d map provided. I assume every vertices will be connected to each other with single direction edges pointing away from the Start node. I assume the resulting graph should be acyclic?
2. Initialize every edges' capacity with 1 (?) as I don't want the algorithm to go through the same path more than once.
3. Run Max Flow algorithm (Ford-Fulkerson, Dinic, or Karp-Edmond) on that graph and the Max flow is the minimum cut needed to prevent A from reaching B.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: The graph you run flow on doesn't need to be acyclic, iirc

Comment: Your approach is close, but you'll actually need to do something a little more technical than that. Remember, it's not that you can't move between any one edge on a cell more than once, but you can't even enter a cell twice. Make sure there's an edge with capacity 1 that represents using the cell at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is a classic example of the identity that **Min Cut = Max Flow**. Let's break this down:
The question can be generalized: Given a graph, and a start and and end, what is the **Min** number of edges to **Cut** such that there is no path from start to end. This can be solved by an algorithm called **Max Flow**. Thus, to solve this problem, construct a graph where each node is connected to all of the non-blocked cells adjacent to it (note directed or non-directed edges) and run Max Flow to get your result.

Comment: We're cutting nodes, not edges, so starting from the obvious graph, you'll need to splice in a gadget for each node.

Comment: I mean yes, but I wanted the user to figure out *how* to construct the graph, to leave some of the problem to them but not leave them floundering on discovering a very difficult algorithm :)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat sorry but, what do you mean by 'splice in a gadget for each node'?

Comment: If you understand the max flow algorithm, you'll see that you don't really want to restrict the edges of the trivial graph that connect cells. Rather, you want to restrict each cell such that only one flow can pass through. Therefore, you want to make the graph with all the edges having very high capacity (4 is the maximum possible answer, so any edge with cap >=4 will be infinite) and have a choke edge with cap of 1 representing the cell *itself*

Answer (score 1):

As @jacob-steinebronn has mentioned max cut min flow will definetly work in the general case but it will be an overkill if,
Assuming that we can only traverse in 4 directions, and also assuming that B is at the ending position(lower right corner), answer can be at max 2. Just block the above and left position of B.
So possibilities can be 0,1,2
**Check for 0**
For 0 just run a simple dfs and check whther you can visit the last cell or not.
**If 0 not feasible:**
**Check for 1**
Check if blocking any guy can prevent it from going .
Just run a bfs level order traversal, if at any level you enocounter only 1 a
single guy that implies that it will be the bottle neck node and just block it.
Proof->Since its a level order bfs traversal  to reach a guy at level i you must cross level  j where  j<i . If there exists only a single guy at that level=> you can't cross level j, Hence can't reach level i.
**If even 1 not feasible**
Answer will be 2